# A problem of J. E. Littlewood

Tags: solid-geometry

Many years ago I picked up a little book by J. E. Littlewood and was baffled by part of a question he posed:

"Is it possible in 3-space for seven infinite circular cylinders of unit radius each to touch all the others? Seven is the number *suggested by counting constants*."

It is the bit in italics which baffled me then (and still does). Can anyone explain how he gets 7 by "counting constants"?

P.S. For completeness, the book is "Some problems in Real and Complex Analysis" (1968)

Comment: I do not know about this problem but there is a related problem for spheres posed by Donald Coxeter: see http://www.popmath.org.uk/sculpture/pages/5firm.html and the linked explanation. The answer for spheres is 5. I do not know if he ever considered cylinders.

Comment: Many thanks. I definitely like that sculpture!

Comment: Should we think of the cylinders as being solid (like the spheres in the sculpture), or are they allowed to intersect? The terms "touch" implies tangency to me, but I thought I'd check.

Comment: He doesn't make it clear in the book, but I would assume he means solid and that he is talking about tangency.

Comment: Yeah, otherwise you could just have them all intersect easily.

Comment: Put 6 cylinders around a central cylinder

Comment: But how can we be sure that each of the six cylinders touches each of the other 5?

Comment: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SevenCylinders/

Comment: Nice animation! However, those cylinders are not infinite (in both directions), which I assume Littlewood intended - could it be modified to work with doubly-infinite cylinders? The real question in my mind, though is how Littlewood arrived at such a conjecture "by counting constants".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is my take: There are $4$ degrees of freedom in selecting the center line of each cylinder, for a total of $4n$ degrees of freedom. Subtract from this the $6$ degrees of freedom given by the Euclidean motions (rotations and translations in space), as applied to the total configuration – for a total of $4n-6$ degrees of freedom.

For two cylinders to touch, the minimal distance between points on their respective center lines must be $2$. This results in $\binom{n}{2}$ equations. To be able to satisfy all these equations, we must probably have $4n-6\ge\binom{n}{2}$, which holds for $n\le7$.

Comment: Interesting! I think this might be a tough one to decide which to accept :)

Comment: @OldJohn So wait for the dust to settle before deciding.